# PrimeFaces dynamic disabling and enabling buttons actionListener does not get fired

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My xhtml looks like this:

```
 <p:dataTable
    rowKey="#{item.idMajor}"
    editable="true"
    selectionMode="single"
    value="#{majorController.beans}" 
    selection="#{majorController.selectedBean}"
    var="item"
    id="majorsTable"
    lazy="true"
    paginator="true"
    rows="5"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"       
    >
    <p:column headerText="Nazwa">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.nameAsEnum.toString()}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText ="Symbol">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.symbolAsEnum.toString()}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:ajax update=":form1:adminView:deleteMajorButton,
            :form1:adminView:editMajorButton,
            :form1:adminView:connectSubjectsButton"

            event="rowSelect"/>
    <p:ajax update=":form1:adminView:deleteMajorButton,
            :form1:adminView:editMajorButton,
            :form1:adminView:connectSubjectsButton" 

            event="rowUnselect"/>
</p:dataTable>
<p:commandButton    value="Nowy"
                    type="button" 
                    onclick="newMajorDlg.show()"
                    />
<p:commandButton value="Usuń"
                 actionListener="#{majorController.onClickDelete()}"
                 id="deleteMajorButton"
                 process="@this,majorsTable"
                 disabled="#{not majorController.itemSelected}"
                 update=":form1"/>
<p:commandButton value="Edytuj"
                 process="@this,majorsTable"
                 id="editMajorButton"
                 update=":form1:adminView:editMajorDialog"
                 disabled="#{not majorController.itemSelected}"
                 oncomplete="editMajorDlg.show()"/>
<p:commandButton value="Przypisz przedmioty"
                 actionListener="#{majorController.loadPickList()}"
                 id="connectSubjectsButton"
                 disabled="#{not majorController.itemSelected}"
                 process="@this,majorsTable"
                 update=":form1:adminView:subjectPickListDialog"
                 oncomplete="subjectPickDlg.show()"
                 />
```

I try to disable button when there is no item selected in datatable.
Disabling and enabling buttons works correctly but after enable button action listener
connected to this button does not get fire.

Thank you for help in advatage.

Comment: Do the buttons work before disabling them? Can you confirm from your browser's javascript console that the buttons are indeed enabled and sending requests to the server when you click on them? My hunch is that the buttons don't get properly enabled and that's why the commands are being ignored during request processing